# ESLint error in Mout.js throttling function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint, throttling

I'm trying to use the Mout.js throttling function in my application.

Here's the code:

```
/**
 * @version 0.1.0 (2012/11/27)
 */
export default function throttle(fn, delay) {
    let context;
    let timeout;
    let result;
    let args;
    let cur;
    let diff;
    let prev = 0;
    function delayed() {
        prev = Date.now();
        timeout = null;
        result = fn.apply(context, args);
    }
    function throttled() {
        context = this;
        args = arguments;
        cur = Date.now();
        diff = delay - (cur - prev);
        if (diff <= 0) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            prev = cur;
            result = fn.apply(context, args);
        } else if (!timeout) {
            timeout = setTimeout(delayed, diff);
        }
        return result;
    }
    return throttled;
}
```

however, ESLint says the following:

> ESLint: Use the rest parameters instead of 'arguments'. (prefer-rest-params)

At the `args = arguments;` line. I tried looking at the docs for `rest-params`, but am having trouble figuring out what's going on.

Comment: `throttled(...rest)` and `args = rest`. Assigning the `arguments` object directly to another variable, especially in sloppy mode, _destroys_ optimization because the `arguments` object keeps a live list of parameters whenever the named parameters are re-assigned within the body of the function. In strict mode this behavior does not occur, but it still reduces the amount of assumptions the JIT compiler can make about the code when executing, which results in slower code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments object is not a proper array. That ESLint rule encourages you to not use it.

See the docs for arguments to get an idea of the kind of special handling required to work with the arguments object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

As Patrick said in the comments, the solution is to use rest parameters like this:

```
function throttled(...rest) {
    context = this;
    args = rest;
    cur = Date.now();
    diff = delay - (cur - prev);
    if (diff <= 0) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        prev = cur;
        result = fn.apply(context, args);
    } else if (!timeout) {
        timeout = setTimeout(delayed, diff);
    }
    return result;
}
```

See the docs for rest parameters for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

Comment: No need for 2 variables, just use `...args`